# Managing ever-growing CSS stylesheets at server-side - are there any libraries, helpers?

Tags: asp.net, css, html-helper

When developing large application using ASP.NET (MVC or classic, doesn't matter), especially in large team, it is easy to produce a lot of messy, non-traceable CSS definitions. After some time we can end up not knowing why particular definition exists and what is its real effect considering style inheritance and cross-browser differences. Needless to say, changing anything in that mess is a risk and there are hundreds of ways how small change could affect the system.

I know some solutions to organize CSS stylesheets better, like predefined CSS "frameworks" or [DotLessCss](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) engine, but I still find it quite hard to cope with CSS as there is no such relationship between HTML markup and CSS styles like i.e. between interface and concrete class in C# code. I know this is by design to make presentation separate from the structure, but I believe it might be useful to have such a correspondence at development level.

Ideally, I need something that can enforce the team not to make messy CSS or be able to clean that mess up automatically. Do you know any resources that may help me, or any guidance how to manage my CSS definitions easily?

**Let me ask for something a bit different:**

Despite of my several years of web experience, I believe I would feel much more confident if some of my CSS could be moved **into C# code**, the same way as some of HTML generation is done by MVC HTML Helpers. It saves me writing a lot of unnecessary markup, still allowing to do so if needed. And it is more unit testable, easier to refactor using tools like ReSharper etc.

I don't need mergers and compressors of my CSS, I would like to be able to manage my CSS at declaration level.

Maybe there are some tools like that I'm not aware of, or maybe that idea is just wrong and wouldn't be useful?

Comment: very nice question, I too have the same problem but still haven't found a bullet-proof solution; mostly I search for classes used on both the rendered code and javascripts, and a bit via trial and error and checking some broken layouts, but that's hardly a good method.

Comment: GWT handles this the [best way](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Hello_Stylish_World) I know of, by strong-typing styles and allowing them to be in the same namespace/encapsulation as their related elements. I'm really missing this feature in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I formulated my question in wrong way, but I was hoping to be directed to some existing .NET APIs to define/generate CSS. Looks like there's nothing like that. And according to [the discussion in parallel question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365488/are-there-any-view-helpers-to-generate-css), it may not be as useful as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox plugin [Dust Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) should help to clean up unused selectors.
That being said please read [What's Wrong With CSS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/whats-wrong-with-css.html)

P.S: Please make reading Jeff Atwood's blog a habit :)

Comment: I'm still not convinced that Dust Me Selectors is how we should do it. It's like late bug fixing instead of early quality assurance, but anyway it'll be useful for sure, it's better to have this at least, thanks!

Comment: I'm definitely not convinced about DustMe, it doesn't help you clean up.. it only highlights potentials.. and  having recently ran trials about the difference between "unused" and "efficient" selectors the unused part was not worth it, and this was unused across site not per page

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth looking at how Telerik have their css structured in their MVC components.

[Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/)

Comment: I agree. I use the Telerik ScriptRegistrar (free for MVC) and it works really well. I keep separate stylesheets for each View and the ScriptRegistrar neatly consolidates them into a single CSS request.

Comment: does Telerik offer anything more than `ScriptRegistrar`, i.e. to keep track of each single CSS definition? If it's just for merging and compressing stylesheet, this is not what I'm really looking for.

Comment: I was thinking of it more as an example of well structured CSS files. They don't have any tools that I know of that check for unused css classes.